# Filter duplicate messages in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm currently learning PowerShell and I have made a script that returns eventlog errors, is it possible to filter out event log errors with the same "EventID" that occur more than once and instead replace them with for example "x2"?

The code:

`[dateTime]$oneWeekAgo = (get-date).addDays(-7)
$Result = Get-EventLog -LogName Application -After $oneWeekAgo -Entrytype Error | 
Select-Object -Property MachineName, Source, EventID, EntryType, Message, TimeGenerated -Unique  | 
Out-File ".\new\EventViewer.txt"`

Example output from my own PC:

````
MachineName   : PC
Source        : Office 2016 Licensing Service
EventID       : 0
EntryType     : 1
Message       : The description for Event ID '0' in Source 'Office 2016 Licensing Service' cannot be found.  The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display the message, or you may not have 
                permission to access them. 
TimeGenerated : 2019-12-11 06:44:30

MachineName   : PC
Source        : Microsoft-Windows-Perflib
EventID       : 1020
EntryType     : 1
Message       : 
TimeGenerated : 2019-12-11 06:39:05

MachineName   : PC
Source        : Office 2016 Licensing Service
EventID       : 0
EntryType     : 1
Message       : The description for Event ID '0' in Source 'Office 2016 Licensing Service' cannot be found.  The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display the message, or you may not have 
                permission to access them.
TimeGenerated : 2019-12-06 22:50:48```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-6) cmdlet. Example:

```
$Result | Group-Object EventId
```